# Computed Column Specification Based on Primary Key

Tags: sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have a field that I want to compute based on a string and the ID generated when a record is inserted. Basically when a record is save with ID = 1, I need the computed field to read 'string_1' and so on. I am trying this is my formula `(('PV'+'_')+ID)` where PV is the string  and ID is the primary key field in the same row as the data inserted but I'm getting a formula error. If I add quotes around ID then I just get PV_ID which is wrong. Any idea how I can reference the ID field in my formula and fetch the value? 
here is my table row structure(ID,Computedfield,data1,data2). i need computedfield to have the value of the ID field concatenated with a string. any help appreciated
**EDIT**
Using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 STANDARD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear on whether that prefix string is a string literal, or the contents of another column.

If it's a **literal**, you should be able to say:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD ComputedColumn AS 'PV_' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED
```

If it's a string contained in another column, you should be able to define it like this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD ComputedColumn AS PV + '_' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED
```

assuming `PV` is the column (of type `VARCHAR`) containing the prefix string.

The main point is: since you're mixing a literal string, and an `INT` value, you need to **`CAST`** the INT to a string first before being able to concatenate those two.

Comment: Thanks dude. I was forgetting or rather did not know I need to use cast and specify the character type.

Answer (score 2):

Use formula:

```
('PV_'+CAST(ID as varchar))
```

if you want to keep the resulting value - add the `PERSISTED` in the end

Comment: Thanks but marc_s answered first